# Redirect External URL to Download Zip File

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring application that needs to provide zip files stored in Amazon S3. When the user hits the Download button, it calls an endpoint which generates the signed URL using the AWS SDK.
If I paste the generated URL in a tab, this works fine.

But redirecting with Spring is not. Here's the controller:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}/file", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
    @ApiOperation("Download generated file")
    public void downloadExportationFile(@PathVariable int id, 
    HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        RawFile rawFile = rawFileRepository.findById(id);
        String preSignedUrl = preSignUrl.execute(rawFile.getFileName());
        response.sendRedirect(preSignedUrl);
  }
```

I have also tried with `response.setContentType("application/octet-stream")` but it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think your content type is relevant if you are redirecting to another URL. What is the client of the controller expecting? Is it just the file or is it expecting something else, like some RESTful response?

Comment: @jbx It is expecting just the file.

Comment: Did you try to debug it on Chrome Dev Tools or Postman from the client side? Did you put some logging in that method to make sure it is going through there and generating the right URL?

Comment: @jbx it works when I use the Send and download Postman option.

Comment: If you can convert your rawfile to a byte array you may try response.getOutputStream().write(bytearray)

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that your controller has been called asynchronously from the client? AFAIK async requests returning 302 to "external pages" are _not_ followed.